# Access MainWindow class members from another class

Tags: c++, qt

I googled a lot before writing here. I found a couple of posts but I couldn't quite get them. So I'm starting a new post.

I am developing a simple UI. There is this main class (see below), which is a main dialogue box which is shown when the app is started.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
```

There are few buttons on the `MainWindow` dialogue box, when I click a button, it hides the `MainWindow` and opens another `QDialog` box. This dialogue box is of the class as shown below

```
class libinsert : public QDialog
```

I create the `libinsert` object this way:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    libinsert lib; // I create libinsert object this way
    lib.setModal(true);
    lib.exec();
}
```

This is `libinsert.cpp`:

```
libinsert::libinsert(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::libinsert)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

When the `libinsert` dialogue box is open, I need to access a socket variable which is a member of `class MainWindow`. How do I achieve this ?

My main app looks like this:

```
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(sock);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
};
```

Alternatively: in general how are multiple dialogue boxes built, as parent-child relation?

Comment: How do you create a libinsert object? Do you pass as a parent to QMainWindow?

Comment: edit your question and add it there, besides I am asking you to show how you create an object of the libinsert class.

Comment: Do you really need to access the `socket` variable from `libinsert`, or do you just want to tell `MainWindow` to do something with the `socket` variable?

Comment: This whole GUI will be running in a separate thread. 2 Sockets are created when the app is started and 1 is given to this GUI thread and the other to the main process. This way both can communicate. and the passing of the socket to the GUI thread occurs only once, so Only MainWindow can hold it(and so I want MainWindow to exists until the app closes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libinsert will not be a child of MainWindow. QDialog-based windows are always top-level windows, regardless of what you pass as their parent when you construct them.

If there will only ever exist a single instance (per process) of MainWindow at any given time, you can give MainWindow a static function which returns a pointer to the window:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        theWindow = this;
    }

    virtual ~MainWindow()
    {
        theWindow = nullptr;
    }

    static get()
    {
        return theWindow;
    }

    static MainWindow *theWindow;
}

MainWindow *MainWindow::theWindow = nullptr;
```

Your dialogs can then access the main window's members thusly:

```
MainWindow::get()->someMemberFunction();
```

A more robust approach is to have libinsert store a pointer to the main window when it is created:

```
class MainWindow;

class libinsert : public QDialog
{
public:
    libinsert(MainWindow *mw)
    : mainWindow(mw)
    { ... }

    MainWindow *getMainWindow()
    {
        return mainWindow;
    }

    MainWindow *mainWindow;
}
```

When MainWindow creates the dialog, it passes a pointer to itself to the constructor:

```
void MainWindow::createDialog()
{
    libinsert *dialog = new libinsert(this):
}
```

This approach will work even if there are multiple instances of MainWindow active at the same time.

Comment: Yes, The MainWindow is only one instance in the process, and it is not multiprocess or Multithreaded app.
Thanks for the reply. I will go with the second approach, it looks elegant. I will try this and get back to this post(Hopefully within tomorrow :P)